# Git merge from another branch - 3 different methods - will all work correctly?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-fetch

I'm working on branch MyFeature, which was created based on branch Develop.

From what I understand, there are (at least) 3 ways to merge Develop back to MyFeature, when I'm checked out on MyFeature:
a. checkout Develop, pull, checkout MyFeature, merge from Develop
b. git fetch, merge from origin/Develop
c. git pull from origin/Develop

I don't like method a (the one I used most before I switched to using method b) cause it's too long and confusing.

Will all these methods produce the same result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, all of these boil down to :

1. `git fetch` (implied in `git pull` scenarios)
2. `git merge origin/develop`

Your method `a` adds a step but keeps your local `Develop` up-to-date. Might be worth or not, depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

If you pull remote changes with the flag --rebase, then your local changes are reapplied on top of the remote changes.

```
git pull --rebase
```

Comment: This is by far my preferred approach when working on feature branches. It lets you deal with any conflicting changes in a more natural way: instead of merging Develop into your own branch, and adjusting Develop's code where it conflicts with your new code, you're 'replaying' your new code onto the latest from Develop, and then getting the opportunity to make adjustments to your own code where it conflicts with the expectations there. That's much more natural.